# Queuing Messages When Internet Not Available in XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

In my chat application, when I am sending messages/chats to the sender , I am checking the internet connection and the XMPP connection. If both are available, then only I allow the user to send the chat messages.

E.g -

```
if(connection.IsConnected){

//code to send the message to the sender
}
```

**I am using Openfire Server.**

I want to implement a functionality that when the internet is not available and when the user wants to send the message, it should send (i.e the messages should be added in the queue) and should send to the receipient as soon as internet is available again , just as Whats App.

Thanks

Comment: Which Xmpp server you are using?

Comment: Am using ejabbered xmpp server do you have any knowledge about that? thanks. I can able to connect with server **Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required. ** getting this message

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can you please help me with any useful hyperlink regarding smack library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is irrelevant in this case if you have no internet/XMPP connection.  You just want to buffer the messages in your client and send them once your connection is reestablished.

I will assume you are using Smack or asmack, which means you will want to simply create a connection listener on your connection so that you can send buffered messages when the connection connection is reestablished.

```
connection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener()
{
      :
    public void reconnectionSuccessful()
    {
        resendFromBuffer();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Robin. I have managed to use Connection Listener. But how to buffer the messages ?? Can you please help ?

Comment: I am successfully moving in the code - reconnectionSuccessful, but I dont know how to store the messages to the buffer. Please help

Comment: That will be your own code.  Smack doesn't provide any such functionality.  Just do it in a send method after you check for the connection (like in your example).